# How to configure Mongodb MMS to go via a Proxy?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

How to I change the monitoring-agent.config to go out via proxy with authentication?

The change log states...

Monitoring Agent 2.3.1.89-1
Released 2014-07-08
Added support for HTTP proxy configuration in the agent configuration file.

But I can't see how to do this.

---

Following wdberkeley's link I can add this value to the monitoring-agent.config file.

httpProxy=http://"pxproxy01":3128

But this gives..

Failure getting conf. Op: Get Err: Proxy Authentication Required

Is there anyway to set the authentication user/password ?

Comment: Check out the [proxy config options](http://mms.mongodb.com/help/reference/monitoring-agent/#http-proxy-settings)

Comment: Thanks! but I can't see an option for Authentication. e.g. something like... httpProxy=porterj:password@<ipaddress>:3128   ??? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you specify the auth with the url? Otherwise you can use SSL. If you can't use either of those, I'd check out the help and support section in MMS (bottom left of screen while logged in, I think) and, if there's no info there, you can file an MMS help ticket from that same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit file:

```
C:\MMSData\Monitoring\monitoring-agent.config
```

Add line...

```
httpProxy=http://<insert_server_address>:<insert_port>
```

e.g.

```
httpProxy=http://PROXY01.server.com:3128
```

Then get the proxy control team, who ever they be, to exclude the following from requiring authentication.

https://mms.mongodb.com 80

https://mms.mongodb.com 443

This has worked for me. I now have the MMS Agent on Windows sending stat's to the MMS service.

Thanks to @wdberkeley for starting me off on this route. 
wdberkeley, the page you linked to does not exist & the classic page PDF & HTTP versions state 'HTTP_PROXY' not 'httpproxy' (on OSx section & tar.gz section), section '6.6 Monitoring Agent Configuration' does state the correct property name 'httpproxy'.